# MessagePack and datetime

Tags: python, datetime, python-3.x, zeromq, msgpack

I need a fast way to send 300 short messages a second over `zeromq` between the python multiprocessing processes. Each message needs to contain an **`ID`** and **`time.time()`**

**`msgpack`** seems like the best way to serialize the dict before sending it via `zeromq`, and conveniently, `msgpack` has an example of exactly what I need, except it has a `datetime.datetime.now()`.

```
import datetime

import msgpack

useful_dict = {
    "id": 1,
    "created": datetime.datetime.now(),
}

def decode_datetime(obj):
    if b'__datetime__' in obj:
        obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(obj["as_str"], "%Y%m%dT%H:%M:%S.%f")
    return obj

def encode_datetime(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, datetime.datetime):
        return {'__datetime__': True, 'as_str': obj.strftime("%Y%m%dT%H:%M:%S.%f")}
    return obj


packed_dict = msgpack.packb(useful_dict, default=encode_datetime)
this_dict_again = msgpack.unpackb(packed_dict, object_hook=decode_datetime)
```

The problem is that their example doesn't work, I get this error:

```
    obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(obj["as_str"], "%Y%m%dT%H:%M:%S.%f")
KeyError: 'as_str'
```

Maybe because I'm on python 3.4, but I don't know what the issue with strptime. Would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python3 and Python2 manage differently strings encoding : [encoding-and-decoding-strings-in-python-3-x](http://www.pythoncentral.io/encoding-and-decoding-strings-in-python-3-x/)

Then it is needed to :

- use `b'as_str'` (instead of `'as_str'`) as dictionary key
- use `encode` and `decode` for the stored value

Modifying the code like this works with python2 and python3 :

```
import datetime
import msgpack

useful_dict = {
    "id": 1,
    "created": datetime.datetime.now(),
}

def decode_datetime(obj):
    if b'__datetime__' in obj:
        obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(obj[b'as_str'].decode(), "%Y%m%dT%H:%M:%S.%f")
    return obj

def encode_datetime(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, datetime.datetime):
        obj = {'__datetime__': True, 'as_str': obj.strftime("%Y%m%dT%H:%M:%S.%f").encode()}
    return obj


packed_dict = msgpack.packb(useful_dict, default=encode_datetime)
this_dict_again = msgpack.unpackb(packed_dict, object_hook=decode_datetime)
```

Answer (score 4):

Given that messagepack ( `import msgpack` ) is good at serializing integers, I created a solution which only uses integers:

```py
_datetime_ExtType = 42

def _unpacker_hook(code, data):
    if code == _datetime_ExtType:
        values = unpack(data)

        if len(values) == 8:  # we have timezone
            return datetime.datetime(*values[:-1], dateutil.tz.tzoffset(None, values[-1]))
        else:
            return datetime.datetime(*values)

    return msgpack.ExtType(code, data)


# This will only get called for unknown types
def _packer_unknown_handler(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, datetime.datetime):
        if obj.tzinfo:
            components = (obj.year, obj.month, obj.day, obj.hour, obj.minute, obj.second, obj.microsecond, int(obj.utcoffset().total_seconds()))
        else:
            components = (obj.year, obj.month, obj.day, obj.hour, obj.minute, obj.second, obj.microsecond)

        # we effectively double pack the values to "compress" them
        data = msgpack.ExtType(_datetime_ExtType, pack(components))
        return data

    raise TypeError("Unknown type: {}".format(obj))

def pack(obj, **kwargs):
    # we don't use a global packer because it wouldn't be re-entrant safe
    return msgpack.packb(obj, use_bin_type=True, default=_packer_unknown_handler, **kwargs)


def unpack(payload):
    try:
        # we temporarily disable gc during unpack to bump up perf: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/msgpack-python
        gc.disable()
        # This must match the above _packer parameters above.  NOTE: use_list is faster
        return msgpack.unpackb(payload, use_list=False, encoding='utf-8', ext_hook=_unpacker_hook)
    finally:
        gc.enable()
```

Comment: btw, I realized later this this particular solution is good at maintaining the original timezone..however a better solution would be to use a utc timestamp if we have a timezone, otherwise do the date serialization.

Answer (score 0):

In the [documentation](http://msgpack-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#msgpack.Packer) it says that the default encoding of unicode strings of `packb` (and `pack`) is utf-8. You could simply search for the unicode string `'__datetime__'` in the `decode_datetime` function, instead of the byte object `b'__datetime__'`, and add the `encoding='utf-8'` parameter to `unpack`. Like so:

```
def decode_datetime(obj):
    if '__datetime__' in obj:
        obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(obj["as_str"], "%Y%m%dT%H:%M:%S.%f")
    return obj

packed_dict = msgpack.packb(useful_dict, default=encode_datetime)
this_dict_again = msgpack.unpackb(packed_dict, object_hook=decode_datetime, encoding='utf-8')
```